# while installing jboss tool luna 4.0 in eclipse market but not able to install

Tags: java

I have installed jdk 1.8, eclipse luna 4.4.0 and jboss EAP 6.3

While installing Jboss Tool(luna) 4.0 CR1 in marketplace in eclipse I got the error like below

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,     
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unable to read repository at http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases   
/jbosstools-4.2.0.CR1-updatesite-core/plugins    
/org.jboss.tools.common.projecttemplates_3.6.0.CR1-v20140829-2038-B51.jar.pack.gz.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases    
/jbosstools-4.2.0.CR1-updatesite-core/plugins
/org.jboss.tools.common.projecttemplates_3.6.0.CR1-v20140829-2038-B51.jar.
Read timed out
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/targetplatforms/jbtcentraltarget
/4.40.0.CR1-SNAPSHOT/REPO/plugins/org.jboss.tools.forge.runtime_1.4.144.CR1-
v20140912-2255-B61.jar.pack.gz download.jboss.org
```

please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this url [JBoss Tool for Eclipse Kepler](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/webtools/kepler/). There is no **Generic JBoss Server Configuration** in Eclipse Luna. I have JBoss Tool installed in my Eclipse with this url.

OR

You can download both the *Kepler* & *Luna* versions of Eclipse from [Eclipse Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Go to below path

```
Eclipse -> plugins 

Copy org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.jboss_1.6.100.v20130422_1357 folder
& org.jboss.netty_3.2.5.Final-20130531-2315.jar from above mentioned location & 
paste them in Eclipse Luna plugins folder.
```

Restart Eclipse & you will get JBoss Tools.

Comment: after the installing JBoss Tool(kepler) i got that not able to complete the installation requested. even though i gave conform then it got like this 'An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing Process Information".
java.lang.NullPointerException' Is any problem form this error

Comment: Will you elaborate more, what u did & how u got this error ? I can't understand from above comment.

Comment: Thank you for giving answer